# Prevent esc from exiting fullscreen mode

Tags: javascript, firefox

My webpage converted to full screen mode using this following code.

```
    var element = document.getElementById("b");


    if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) {

      element.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (element.webkitRequestFullScreen) {

      element.webkitRequestFullScreen();
   }
```

I want to prevent exit from fullscreen mode by clicking esc

I tried this following codes but not working.

```
document.onkeydown = function (evt) {
            alert("1");
    if (evt.keyCode == 27) evt.preventDefault();
}
```

If i press escape it first exit from full screen and from next press the above function will work and alert "1".

I tried the following codes also but no benefit

```
  function keyUp(){
    alert("sdd");
document.querySelector("#start").addEventListener("keydown",function(e){
    var charCode = e.charCode || e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (charCode == 27){

        return false;
    }
});

}
```

and

```
document.onkeydown = function (e) {
        if(e.which == 27){
                return false;
        }
}
```

Anybody know how to prevent exiting from full screen mode. Or how to convert webpage to fullscreen mode using f11 key programatically?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? This would be annoying and I wouldn't visit your site again.

Comment: I certainly hope browser are not stupid and browser hijacking like that doesn't work. Otherwise it would be an epic failure in my eyes from the side of browser vendors / w3c.

Comment: @LeeTaylor@PeeHaa in banking exam we cant escape from full screen mode, I want that functionality

Comment: And that is solved programmatically from the browser? I hope not...

Comment: @PeeHaa ok anyother way to change in fullscreen and prev esc button?

Comment: I know chrome has a `--kiosk` flag

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  For example in Chrome Packaged Apps, where it acts like a native app and not a browser.

Comment: @LeeTaylor assume a situation where user is taking a test and I want only test window to be opened, only for the duration of 1 hour (till the test comepletes) is such scenario I would use this. It might not be 100% proof but still it is a way to stop user from taking help from other tabs opened (I have to bind events to key pressed events for such combinations)

Comment: I've got a remote desktop running full screen and I'm running Emacs in a remote window.  I use ESC all the time as part of Emacs control sequences, and every time I hit ESC it drops me out of full screen.  This feature cripples full screen for a remote desktop.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Any browsers complying to the standards will not (and should not) let you block this. Quite simply because it would be very intrusive and will confuse the users, who expect to always have a clear "panic button" to escape a screen.

Here are the api specifications:
[Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web/Guide/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode#Getting_out_of_full_screen_mode)
[W3C](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/fullscreen/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#security-and-privacy-considerations)

Answer (score 2):

That's impossible from pure js. The API is designed to allow the user to exit the fullscreen mode at any time.

The only thing cou can try is to use the `fullscreenchange` event to detect when the fullscreen is disabled, and then enable it again.
But the browser will probably alert the user and he will always be able to disallow your website to use fullscreen.

I don't encourage you to do it. That's really a bad idea. I would probably ragequit (and never return) a website which tries that.

Comment: It's not a bad idea in chrome packaged apps so the original question is valid in that context.

Comment: It's not a bad idea at all. What if I want to make my iPad to act in Kiosk-like mode? Yeah I know it's not possible, it's better to create a native app (and even this is not the real solution). And even better — use a special touchscreen and RaspberryPi.

Comment: one valid reason to temporarily disable escape is to allow the user to close a context menu that's being displayed over a fullscreen app, with one press of escape. you really don't want the whole page to collapse on itself when the natural meaning of escape in that context is to back out one level...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `navigator.keyboard.lock();` to prevent the escape key from exiting full screen mode (or from unlocking the pointer for that matter).

Though it's only supported in Chromium based browsers and still allows the user to exit full screen by holding down the escape key.

Check out the [Keyboard API MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Keyboard_API#keyboard_locking).